# How to get labels from GitHub using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, github, alamofire

I would like to know how to get labels from user setting. I know how to post selected labels to a user's repository.

```
 let authToken = GithubAPIManager.sharedInstance.OAuthToken
    let repo = newIssue.repo!.name!
    let repoOwner = newIssue.repo!.ownerLogin!


    let URL = Foundation.URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/\(repoOwner)/\(repo)/labels")!

    print("Issue URL ---->", URL)

    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: getParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {

        (response) in

        guard let object = response.result.value else {
            print(response.result.error!)
            completionHandler(.failed)
            return
        }

        completionHandler(.success)
        print(object)

    }
```

Comment: What in your current solution is not working?

Comment: I just have no idea how to deal with this. In the github, I read how to use and I found this but not sure how to implement this.  ---> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/labels/:name

Comment: What does GET /repos/:owner/:repo/labels/:name mean?